# How to set ungreedy option in TDIPerlRegEx regex

Tags: regex, delphi

I am using pattern like this:

```
RegEx_Seek.MatchPattern := '(*UCP)(?m)(?<=can he )(not ){0,2}\w\w+(?= )';
```

I want to capture the word **answer**. But I got only not in the result. The capture of not does not mind to me. The problem is that answer was not captured.

From [help page](https://www.yunqa.de/delphi/products/regex/syntax):
Option settings:

> (?U)           default ungreedy (lazy)   (?x)           extended
>   (ignore white space)   (?-...)        unset option(s)

So I tried `(*CP)(?-U)(?m)` but the pattern with this is not compiled.

Example text:
They bear him upon the shoulder, they carry him, and set him in his place, and he standeth; from his place shall he not remove: yea, one shall cry unto him, yet **can he not answer**, nor save him out of his trouble.

Yet I am using more complicated pattern to search for verbs:

```
  RegEx_Seek_1.MatchPattern := '(*UCP)(?m)(?<=can he )(also |alone |myself |otherwise |who |not ){0,2}{0,2}\w\w+(?= )';
```

so basicly I do not want to change the structure of the pattern, but just to disable the greedy option which is used on 'not ' word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
(*UCP)\bcan\s+he\s+(?:not\s+){0,2}\K\w{2,}
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ktbLNo/2)

**Details**

- `(*UCP)` - a PCRE verb making all shorthands Unicode aware
- `\bcan` - a whole word `can` (`\b` is a word boundary)
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `he` - the `he` word
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `(?:not\s+){0,2}` - 0, 1 or 2 occurrences of `not` and then 1+ whitespaces
- `\K` - match reset operator
- `\w{2,}` - 2 or more word chars.

Comment: What is main difference between my and your expression? In my pattern if I add (?:not ) so it does not help. I would have the 'not' in result.... Is it the word boundary or the \K match reset operator, what does the main job of excluding not from result?

Comment: @user1141649 You had a `(?= )` lookahead that required a space after 2 or more word chars. Due to it, `(\w\w+)` could not match `answer` (that is followed with `,`) and since `(not ){0,2}` can match an empty string, the `\w\w+` matched `not`  after backtracking. The `\K` is a good replacement for a positive lookbehind when no overlapping matches are expected, just like in this case.

Comment: I have tried to modify my pattern according your information: `(*UCP)(?m)(?<=can he )(not ){0,2}\K\w+` this works now. Thank you.

Comment: @user1141649 It won't work if you have 2 or more spaces between `can` and `he`, or `not` and the next word. `(?m)` is redundant, you have no `^` and `$` in the pattern.